# Ajax redirect from php after succes

Tags: ajax

So another problem here. I think this problem is not hard to solve. But I do not have a lot of experiences with Ajax yet.

My problem is I want to redirect after success. For better imagination, I attach only if statement from login code here.

```
if ($row['odd_zam'] == 1) {
        $_SESSION['name'][0] = $row['skratka_titul']." ".$row['meno_zam']." ".$row['priezvisko_zam']." ".$row['skratka_titul'];
        $_SESSION['name'][2] = 1;   // 1 = otk
        $_SESSION['name'][3] = $row['prava_zam'];
        $n = header('Location: otk/index-test.php');
        echo $n;
    }
    if ($row['odd_zam'] == 2) {
        $_SESSION['name'][0] = $row['skratka_titul']." ".$row['meno_zam']." ".$row['priezvisko_zam']." ".$row['skratka_titul'];
        $_SESSION['name'][2] = 2;   // 2 = eir
        $_SESSION['name'][3] = $row['prava_zam'];
        $n = header('Location: eir/index.php');
        echo $n;
    }
    if ($row['prava_zam'] == 3) {
        $_SESSION['name'][0] = $row['skratka_titul']." ".$row['meno_zam']." ".$row['priezvisko_zam']." ".$row['skratka_titul'];
        $_SESSION['name'][2] = 3;   // 3 = spravca
        $_SESSION['name'][3] = $row['prava_zam'];
        $n = header('Location: zam/index.php');
        echo $n;
    }
```

And in my ajax code i do this:

```
success: function(data){
            window.location.href = data;
        }
```

But a problem is this code logs me but it do not redirect me.
I tried `window.location.href = data.n;` but this do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the successs function you can reload the same page by using `location.reload();` Javascript function.

```
success: function(data){
    location.reload();
}
```

If however you want to reload to a different page then mention the page address like so :

```
success: function(data){
    window.location.href = 'path to reload file';
}
```

Comment: i want to reload page to my $n variable which i definde in login php and redirect to this variabil from success function

Comment: Create a Session variable for $n and then inside the success function use window.location = '<?php echo $name_of_session_id_containing_$n_value?>'; . This will redirect you to the page stored inside $n;

Answer (score 0):

You have a bit of confusion here.

[header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) is used to send a raw HTTP header.
Additionally, it does not return a value, so your `$n` will always be `null`.

You have to change your code:

```
if ($row['odd_zam'] == 1) {
        $_SESSION['name'][0] = $row['skratka_titul']." ".$row['meno_zam']." ".$row['priezvisko_zam']." ".$row['skratka_titul'];
        $_SESSION['name'][2] = 1;   // 1 = otk
        $_SESSION['name'][3] = $row['prava_zam'];
        $n = "otk/index-test.php";
        echo $n;
    }
    if ($row['odd_zam'] == 2) {
        $_SESSION['name'][0] = $row['skratka_titul']." ".$row['meno_zam']." ".$row['priezvisko_zam']." ".$row['skratka_titul'];
        $_SESSION['name'][2] = 2;   // 2 = eir
        $_SESSION['name'][3] = $row['prava_zam'];
        $n = "eir/index.php";
        echo $n;
    }
    if ($row['prava_zam'] == 3) {
        $_SESSION['name'][0] = $row['skratka_titul']." ".$row['meno_zam']." ".$row['priezvisko_zam']." ".$row['skratka_titul'];
        $_SESSION['name'][2] = 3;   // 3 = spravca
        $_SESSION['name'][3] = $row['prava_zam'];
        $n = "zam/index.php";
        echo $n;
    }
```

In this way you can do this:

```
success: function(data){
            window.location.href = data;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
success:function(data) { 
            window.location.href = 'url?param=' + data
        }
```